# Creating Windows device drivers

Tags: windows, driver, windows-kernel

I am wanting to make custom mouse, keyboard, and controller drivers for windows. That being said I know theres already default drivers out there but how can I find their source code? I really want to learn how all of these work then make my own custom ones based off of the default ones. Does anyone know where I can find any source code for the above devices?

Answer (score 0):

You can refer to the samples here https://github.com/debojyoti-majumder/Windows-driver-samples/tree/master/hid/hclient

First you should understand a little bit about HID clients, and I think this https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/samples/human-interface-devices--hid--driver-samples should help you.

Comment: What sort of samples are these because they don't appear to be strictly for controller, mouse, or keyboard. Also in particular I am looking to make a physical device driver not just a filter style driver that works on top of other drivers.